# Running javascript from the "userside"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imacros

I have one maybe stupid question but my googling skill were not up to the task.

I have some html page that I opet at my work that is php generated. On it 80% of the text is not needed for me so I "made" a javascript code that filters/hides all text I am not interested in. It works just fine but for this to work I must SAVE html document on my computer and insert that javascript code into it so it can make text invisible.
Now I am thinking of improving this because every time I reload web page on my company's server I need to save it on computer and insert javascript code.
Please point me into the direction that can help me do this. Is there any way to run that javascript code over already opened page in FireFox or some other browsers?

Html page that I am changing is mostly tables and I am hiding rows that I do not need, but there aro around 500 rows and I only need 15 or 20.

Thank for all your effort!

Comment: It sounds like you want [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to inject a user generated script into an existing web page in your own browser.

Comment: Another alternative is to create a bookmarklet.

Comment: sounds like you need to edit the php code to be the right `select` statement.  Or you can add to the `.php` file a reference to your javascript.

Comment: I will look what greasemonkey can do and get back to you.

Comment: I can't change the serverside at any point, I just can help myself with filtering unusable things from html page. I paste the javascript code into greasemonkey but nothing happens... will read greasemonkey help if any but you may give me advices here if you have some for starters.

Comment: Is there a difference between jquery and javascript? I have jquery code for this and I just can;t insert it correctly to the greasemonkey.
$(document).ready( function() {
$('td:contains("Router Alias")').parents("tr").remove();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a '[bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)'. Those are small javascript snippets, which you can insert into your bookmark bar and then execute by clicking on them.

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){alert(1);})()">Drag me to bookmarks for alert</a>
```

For Example, drag the link in this fiddle into your bookmark bar and it will alert 1 on click.
http://jsfiddle.net/5aAPN/2/

Comment: Rather than making a link and dragging it, you can also just go through the new bookmark creation process, and just put `javascript:<code here>` in the URL field.

Comment: I tried but nothing happens. In FireFox in NEW BOOKMARK URL field I wrote: javascript: "javascriptcode" and nothing happens when I open my html page and click BOOKMARK.
In my javascript code I have commands <script> </script> and calling external sources for scripts. Does it change something?

Comment: @Djusko it should just be javascript code - no `<script>` tags. Keep your developer console open to check for errors.

Comment: This is what I put in. %20 is automatically added by FireFox when I copy/paste the code.

javascript:src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"%20type="text/javascript"%20$(document).ready(%20function()%20{%20$('td:contains("Router%20Alias")').parents("tr").remove();%20});%20$(document).ready(%20function()%20{%20$('td:contains("DS091%20-%20Ministarstvo%20poljoprivrede%20ex%20Kosava")').parents("tr").remove();%20});%20$(document).ready(%20function()%20{%20$('td:contains("DS173%20-%20NIS")').parents("tr").remove();%20});%20

There are many more but you'll see the pattern

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead. If you have a white background make the text white. You can also give visibility: hidden a try.